# Resharper test unit shortcut missing

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

A few months back, I used to be able to click a circle in the code margin, and the given unit test would run (attributes [TestFixture] / [Test]).

Now on my VS2010, the only way to run a single unit test (NUnit is being used) is to type ctrl+alt+U (or do the same via the resharper menu), select the test, and press the debug button.

Anyone know where those code margin buttons went + how to get them back.  The icon was a single circle coloured in two halves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing a new version of Resharper.

Answer (score 3):

which exact version of resharper do you use? I have Resharper 6.1.37.86 and this option is there.

Also try checking resharper options: Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit testing. Both 'Enable unit testing' and 'Enable NUnit support' should be checked.

Comment: Those options are set, and I'm using the same version as you are.